# What lightweight JS tab with good design are you using?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

Right now I am usingjQuery UI Tab but it has a conflict in Drupal's fieldset accordion so I am thinking of using a lightweight javascript tab with a good design like rounded corners that is a javascript framework independent.

What javascript tabs are you using? Or do you know any javascript tabs that is working in drupal and doe's not break the fieldset accordion?

Here are the Javascript tabs I found so far:
- [Coda-Slider](http://www.ndoherty.com/demos/coda-slider/1.1.1)
- [dhtmlxTabbar](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTabbar/index.shtml)

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same jQuery UI Tab and is one of the best. Perhaps it will be a good idea to post the problem and to try fixing the problem. It may or not be related with the plugin and it could happen as well that the problem will not be solved by changing the tab plugin.

Comment: The problem is that the drupal fieldset accordion is not working. It is related to the jQuery UI Tab plugin. I found this: http://drupal.org/node/385762
But I can't fix the error. I already followed the instructions stated there. I just used the "tabbertab", a lightweight JS tab.

Answer (score 0):

I have used jQuery UI Tabs and [jQuery Tools Tabs](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs.html) without any problems. Both are fairly lightweight and very usable.

I think that if it interferes with other parts of your site you should make sure that the selectors that you use are specific enough i.e. give the html elements you want to transform into tabs an id and then set your CSS and Javascript to only change that id.

It might be worth noting that currently [jQuery Tools Tabs](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs.html) uses fixed tab widths and cannot grow arbitrarily long like jQuery UI Tabs.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am using drupal 5 and it conflicts jQuery's UI tab version 3. I don't know why it is working for you? What's the version of your drupal and jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. I was able to fix the fieldset issue with drupal 5 by using a variant of the patch in the link below. Basically, after installing jQuery Update, I had to go to /misc/collapse.js and change line 76 from:

```
.css({height: 'auto', display: 'inline'});
```

to

```
.css({height: 'auto', display: 'none'});
```

And that did the trick for me. Hope it helps you!

**Source**: http://drupal.org/node/156221

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout [dhtmlxTabbar](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTabbar/).